# Trying to create bulk read job for Zoho_Books but getting "Module not Available" from Postman

Tags: zoho

When trying to make a post request to `{{api-domain}}/crm/bulk/v2/read` with a body of

```
{
  "callback": {
    "url": "https://www.personalcalbackurl.com",
    "method": "post"
  },
  "query": {
    "module": "Zoho_Books",
    "page": 1
  }
}
```

I get an error in Postman of

`{"status":"error","code":"MODULE_NOT_AVAILABLE","message":"Requested module Zoho_Books is not available.","details":{"api_name":"Zoho_Books","module":"Zoho_Books"}}`

Is a bulk read not available for the Zoho Books module? The Postman request creates a bulk read job for the `Contacts` module so that's odd that Zoho Finance wouldn't allow a bulk read. I know this is Zoho CRM, but Zoho_Books shows up as Zoho Finance's API name and every time I search for "Bulk Read Zoho Finance" the CRM docs only show up. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom modules based on Zoho Finance inside of Zoho CRM and they'll come back with an API name of "CustomModule###" and you can use that custom module name to create a bulk read job. Worked perfectly!